# Serialize protobuf with default values using Gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to serialize a protobuf message, which is represented as Java class, into JSON with Gson library and [ProtoTypeAdapter](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/proto/src/main/java/com/google/gson/protobuf/ProtoTypeAdapter.java)

```java
ProtoTypeAdapter adapter = ProtoTypeAdapter.newBuilder()
        .setFieldNameSerializationFormat(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE)
        .build();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(SomeAutogeneratedClass.class, adapter)
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .disableHtmlEscaping()
        .create();

suchMessage.getMyIntField()  // which is 0
String serialized = gson.toJson(suchMessage)
```

But it seems that it does not serialize default values such as `0` for `int` field.
How can I include those fields with default value in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I modified [this line](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/aa236ec38d39f434c1641aeaef9241aec18affde/proto/src/main/java/com/google/gson/protobuf/ProtoTypeAdapter.java#L220) as follows:

```java
//        final Map<FieldDescriptor, Object> fields = src.getAllFields();  // original line

        // --- Include default value fields (See com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat) ---
        final Map<FieldDescriptor, Object> fields = new TreeMap<>(src.getAllFields());
        for (FieldDescriptor field : src.getDescriptorForType().getFields()) {
            if (field.isOptional()) {
                if (field.getJavaType() == FieldDescriptor.JavaType.MESSAGE
                        && !src.hasField(field)) {
                    continue;
                }
                Descriptors.OneofDescriptor oneof = field.getContainingOneof();
                if (oneof != null && !src.hasField(field)) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (!fields.containsKey(field)) {
                fields.put(field, src.getField(field));
            }
        }
        // ------
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a little script that uses reflection to fix this by changing the default value to something that can never be used.

```java
public static void overrideDefaultValue(Descriptors.FieldDescriptor desc, Object newDefault) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    Field f = Descriptors.FieldDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField("defaultValue");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(desc, newDefault);
}
```

Let's say you're trying to serialize a value that represent an index. Then `-1` is an impossible value. You can use it like this:

```java
overrideDefaultValue(MyMessage.getDescriptor().findFieldByName("my_field"), -1);
```